# Build artifacts are lost from Travis CI's Openshift deployment

Tags: ember.js, openshift, ember-cli, travis-ci

I'm trying to deploy an Ember CLI app through Travis CI to Openshift. Unfortunately, the `dist` folder (which is generated through Travis's `before_deploy` script), is not getting pushed to Openshift. My `travis.yml` file:

```
before_deploy:
- ember build --environment=production
deploy:
  provider: openshift
  . . . .
  skip_cleanup: true
```

If I do this:

```
before_deploy:
- ember build --environment=production
- ls
```

I can see that the `dist` folder is being generated. However, when I ssh into Openshift, the `dist` folder is missing (along with other artifacts, like the `tmp` folder).

Any idea why this is happening? My first guess was that since the Openshift deployment is git-based, the `dist` folder was being removed because it's in my `.gitignore` file. However, this behavior persists, even after removing it. My second guess is that I might have to manually `git add` it during the `before_deploy`, but that seems like a merge conflict in the making. Plus, I would expect Travis's integration to take care of that already.

So, any ideas? I've been toying with this for hours and still no luck.

Comment: Is your build passing with no problems? Have you check the build log for any hints?

Comment: Surprisingly, it is passing. I was finally able to get this 'working' in my `after_success` hook with `rm -rf .git`, `git init`, and then creating a new commit. It's not pretty, but it gets the deploy working. Hoping there's a better solution out there, though. This approach loses all the benefit of openshift using git.